# openSUSE 42.3 does not start up from USB - black screen after loading kernel

Tags: system-installation, opensuse, startup

I tried to install openSUSE on my desktop PC and load openSUSE 42.3 to my USB stick by using *SUSE Studio Imagewriter* (my laptop is running openSUSE). However, after a while the screen turns black and nothing happens.

My desktop PC loads the GRUB (at least it looks like GRUB) from USB and I choose the option *Installation*. The kernel seems to be loaded and things are printed on the screen. The last things printed on the screen before turning black are:

`>>> openSUSE Leap 42.3 installation program v5.0.104 (c) 1996-2016 SUSE LLC <<<
Starting udev...`

After this, the PC seems to do nothing and my display turns black.
First, I thought this was a problem of the USB stick, downloaded openSUSE a second time, checked its hash, and tried on my laptop (where everything seems to be OK) but nothing changed. Both, the DVD install and Net install showed the same issue or at least symptoms.

So I assume it has something to do with my desktop PC. It has AMD CPU and NVidia graphics card (my laptop has both from Intel). Maybe this needs some special attention?

Any suggestions what could be the problem or what to try next?

Many thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Well, found a solution:

In the grub press key **E** when *Installation* is highlighted. The entry should look like this:

```
setparams 'Installation'

    set gfxpayload=keep
    echo 'Loading kernel ...'
    linuxefi /boot/x86_64/loader/linux splash=silent
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrdefi /boot/x64_86/loader/initrd
```

Add *nomodeset* to the row that starts with *linuxefi*, it looks like that:

```
setparams 'Installation'

    set gfxpayload=keep
    echo 'Loading kernel ...'
    linuxefi /boot/x86_64/loader/linux splash=silent nomodeset
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrdefi /boot/x64_86/loader/initrd
```

Finally pres **F10** to load run.
That did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working on my laptop, which also has an AMD CPU (with graphics) and an NVidia GPU.